# Cannot send session cache limiter - PHP

Tags: php, webserver

I just changed a couple of websites from an old web server to a new one.

This error is occurring in various pages of the e-commerce website.

Any idea of what it could be?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Headers already sent by PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)

Answer (score 1):

this may sometimes happen because of something being send to the browser before the session this could be be a space at the start of a php script or a BOM unicode in your file that cause that problem.

Answer (score 0):

1.Remove Whitespaces before and after PHP Tags. It may give "Cannot send session cache limiter  " Warning.

2.If SESSION is already enabled in PHP.ini, then no need to write session_start(); Statement.

3.If SESSION is disabled in PHP.ini, then keep "session_start();" Statement only once in your application.

Answer (score 0):

This can be because of something that I faced with before:

1. You have something before `session_start();` in your codes. Make sure that this code is the fist line after `<?php` in your code.
2. We have something called **BOM** in php files. You can set or unset this option while you are saving your php file. For PHP files, this option has to be **unset**. Otherwise you will get your mentioned error.